# error in uploading large size image using input

Tags: php, html, file-io

I am trying to upload image of larger size like 4608X3500 pixels using html input tag.
But not able to get file size.

I am using this code to get file details:

```
    $userfile_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$userfile_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$userfile_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

In this, i am not getting type value and size value is showing 0.

Comment: There must be some error while uploading file. Can you show us the `var_dump($_FILES['image']['error']);` ?

Comment: if you get answer then Please Choose any answer which is helpful most.
otherwise you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the file's too large. What does

```
var_dump($_FILES['image']['error'])
```

show? If it's non-zero, an error occured. The codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

Change `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.6

in this search php.ini file and in this file you need to set upload_max_filesize...

Answer (score 0):

Sometime when we upload file with less than 2 MB. It upload normally because by default `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini have 2M thats means 2 MB. On Other hand file size more then 2 MB require changes  in  `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini. You can also check you error with

```
var_dump($_FILES['image']['error'])
```

Here list with there related value

```
UPLOAD_ERR_OK

    Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE

    Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE

    Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL

    Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE

    Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

    Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.
UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE

    Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION

    Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.'
```

Ref here:- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php